# JPA many to one relation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a question regarding ManyToOne relationship.
Assume I have 2 beans:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "accounts")
public class Account {
     @Id
     @Column(name = "account_id")
     private int account_id;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "broker_account")
public class BrokerAccount {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "broker_account_id")
    private int broker_account_id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="account_id", referencedColumnName = "account_id")
    private Account account;
}
```

I am querying the entity below (plain get all query)

```
entityManager.createQuery("from BrokerAccount", BrokerAccount.class)
```

I thought that if I query BrokerAccount entity the account_id column will be populated by default on the Account object, since it exists in the BrokerAccount table as well, however all the Account fields are empty.

Am I missing something, should I define this field/column on the BrokerAccount entity itself as well to get its value?

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the Account association as `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`. This means that while performing the `entityManager.createQuery("from BrokerAccount", BrokerAccount.class)`, there will be no join on the `Account` and its data will not be fetched at that time.

In order to make the persistence provider fetch the `Account` data you would need to interact with the reference while being in the same transactional method, f.e.: `brokerAccount.getAccount().getAccountId();`

If you want to simply have a repeated column for the fk you can do:

```
@Column(name = "account_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private int account_id;
```

Comment: In this case the whole Account entity will be fetched, I was wondering if only account_id should be populated since its part of the BrokerAccount and Account entity, and since I asked for BrokerAccount it would be populated solely on the Account entity without actually fetching it from the DB.

Comment: I know this solves the problem, I was just wondering if I actually need to define it or I am missing something and it should appear on the Account entity.